# Time series prediction with Keras - values close to average

Tags: python, keras

I am doing a one step ahead prediction using 15 previous samples on a dataset using LSTMs in Keras.

The data csv file can be found here: 
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byiipc0dArG0LVZJelB4NFBucms/view?usp=sharing)

The second column col[1] values are used. The values in the first column (timestamps) are not used at all.

I use the following code:

```
# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
        dataX, dataY = [], []
        for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
                a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
                dataX.append(a)
                dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
        return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load the dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('node70-3000.csv', usecols=[1],
engine='python', skipfooter=3)
dataset = dataframe.values
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.7)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], 
dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 15
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)
# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1], 1))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], testX.shape[1], 1))
# create and fit the LSTM network
batch_size = 11
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1),
stateful=True))      
#model.add(LSTM(32, stateful = True))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dense(1))
# default lr=0.001
optim = Adam(lr=0.05, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08,
decay=0.1)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optim)
for i in range(50):
        model.fit(trainX, trainY, nb_epoch=1, batch_size=batch_size,
            verbose=2, shuffle=False)   
        model.reset_states()
# make predictions
```

The problem:

I have used this code to predict few more periodical and clean time series and it works well. For this set of data however, I used different parameters of Adam (learning rate, etc). Still, I get the prediction with a large offset from the actual values. It seems like the predicted values are always close to the average of the data values. Please see the following graph. I have 1850 data points in the csv file. These are grouped into sequences of size 15. The input is a sequence of size 15. The output should be the next value predicted. 70% of the data is used for training and the rest is the test data set. Prediction is done on train and test datasets shown in green and red respectively in the following image.

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byiipc0dArG0OEN5el9lc0puNGM/view?usp=sharing)

Do you have any idea why this is happening and what can be causing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data looks a lot like binary data + noise. 
Below is a histogram of the raw data and a histogram of the first difference of the raw data. If the exact value of the prediction is not important to you, I would suggest making the data binary and using a different cost function, e.g. binary crossentropy, though I'm skeptical that it will work giving the explanation below.

If there are similar sequences with multiple possible next values, the network will try to predict the average value. For example, consider the sequences (0,0,1) and (0,0,0) and (0,0,-1) and a network trying to learn their last values. With this toy data, any prediction model's best MSE is to predict the average of the last values, 0 in this case...

I suggest checking what the network is learning by plotting target values, Y, and predicted target values, Y_hat.
Hope this helps!

[image: Raw Data Histogram] [image: 1st Difference Histogram]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very useful points you mentioned. Using your comments, I started thinking about the nature of my dataset and checked a few things. Does what you suggested imply that there may not be enough pattern/periodicity in the dataset? And the reason the average is being predicted is that the data is perceived as a random set by the network?

Comment: Consider data with two patterns: A) 0 is followed by a 0 or 1 with equal probability; B) 1 is followed by 0 or 1 with equal probability. A model trained minimizing mean squared error will always predict 0.5 because this behavior produces the best loss.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. I'll investigate the characteristics of the data and the input sequences to verify that.